# using Jamon to monitor jBoss EAP 6

Tags: jboss, jamon

i am attempting to use Jamon to monitor a jBoss EAP 6 server.

I have followed the instructions here for Jboss:

http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/http_monitoring.html however i am stuck on this part:

*Add the following Valve line to Tomcat's server.xml file (i.e. jbossweb-tomcat55.sar/server.xml). The 'Engine' line is used to show context.*

My jBoss has no server.xml (i understand previous versions did and i know the above link references 4.x) so what is the equivalent in EAP 6? standalone.xml? if so, how and where would i incorporate the required lines?

The jamon.war is getting deployed but when trying to hit the jamon web console i get a page full of errors which i am assuming is related to me not having the config correct:

*org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 
An error occurred at line: 278 in the jsp file: /jamonadmin.jsp
MonProxyFactory cannot be resolved*

Is anybody able to assist me to get this up and running?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the jamon jar is not in the class path.  Make sure that it is in a place that both the server and the web app can access it.